# Dynamic super() in multi-inheritance in Python

Tags: python

I have code like this:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('X')
    def Print(self):
        print('X')


class Y(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Y')
    def Print(self):
        print('Y')

class Z(X,Y):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Z')
        def Print(self):
            print('z')
            super().Print()

>>> z=Z()
Z
>>> z.Print()
X
```

It searches for `Print` according to

```
Z.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Z'>, <class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.Y'>, <class 'object'>)
```

and find it for first time in `X`.
But if I want to `z.Print()` run `Y.Print()`, I can use an explicit class name like:

```
class Z(X,Y):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Z')
        def Print(self):
            print('z')
            Y.Print()
```

but this is not dynamic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, you could define Z as `class Z(Y, X)` if you want the classes to be inherited in the other order.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: no ,I want to do this with out changing the inheritance orders

Comment: And how do you expect Python to guess which one you want to use if you insist on defining them out of order? You could always do `self.__class__.__bases__[1].Print()` if you always want to pick the 2nd parent class, but if you do, remind me never to work with you..

Comment: @ZeroDays: In what sense do you want it to be "dynamic"?  You can either use the inheritance order, or you can explicitly say which class you want to use, but there aren't really any other options that make sense.  How do you expect Python to know which one you want to use?

Comment: ok. so the beast way here is use explicit class name ?

Comment: If you want to preserve the inheritance order (that is, have all of X's methods take priority over Y's), except for that one call, then yes, I would say using Y explicitly for that call is your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference purposes, here is a summary of the options that were discussed in the comments.

**1. Change the order of inheritance**

```
class Z(Y, X):
    ...
```

That would ensure that Y's methods are called over X's methods when using `super`, including the `Print` method.

**2. Explicitly call Y's Print method**

```
class Z(X, Y):
    ...
    def Print(self):
        Y.Print(self)
```

That would ensure that X's methods are called over Y's methods when using `super`, except for that one call, which would explicitly call Y's `Print`.

**3. (Do not use) Explicitly call the second parent class's method**

```
class Z(X, Y):
    ...
    def Print(self):
        self.__class__.__bases__[1].Print()
```

That would ensure that X's methods are called over Y's methods when using `super`, except for that one call, which would explicitly call the second parent class's `Print` (in this case, Y).

Comment: ok thx. so see here plz : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805738/useless-super-in-multiple-inheritance

Comment: in option 2, that should be `Y.Print(self)`

Answer (score 2):

I really depends what you are trying to do. If you want to make sure both `X.Print` and `Y.Print` are called then you need to add super calls in both `X.Print` and `Y.Print`, and an a base class with a place holder Print method.

If you want to call `X.Print` or `Y.Print` depending on some criteria, then inheritance may be the wrong model for you. You may wish to try using composition. This is where you write a class that *does not* inherit from `X` or `Y`, but has instances of them as members and knows how to use them. eg.

#### Inheritance

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class Base(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def Print(self):
        pass

class X(Base):
    def Print(self):
        print("X")
        super().Print()

class Y(Base):
    def Print(self):
        print("Y")
        super().Print()

class Inheritance(X, Y):
    def Print(self):
        print("Inheiritance")
        super().Print()

Inheritance().Print()
```

Outputs:

```
Inheiritance
X
Y
```

#### Composition

```
class Composition:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = X()
        self.y = Y()
    def Print(self):
        print("Composition")
        self.x.Print()
        self.y.Print()

Composition().Print()
```

Outputs:

```
Composition
X
Y
```

Comment: Without knowing what X, Y and Z are it's though to really know what model applies, but I concur on the composition advice. Composition over Inheritance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).