# useless super in multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance

in multiple inheritance how super() works?
for example here I have Two **init** and I want to send args by super():

```
class LivingThings(object):
    def __init__(self, age ,name):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def Print(self):
        print('age: ', self.age)
        print('name: ', self.name)

class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape=shape
    def Print(self):
        print(self.shape)

class Dog(LivingThings, Shape):
    def __init__(self, breed, age , name, shape):
        self.breed=breed
        super().__init__(age , name)
        super().__init__(shape)


    def Print(self):
        LivingThings.Print(self)
        Shape.Print(self)
        print('breed', self.breed)
```

but error :

```
super().__init__(shape)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

but this code works :

```
class Dog(LivingThings, Shape):
    def __init__(self, breed, age , name, shape):
        self.breed=breed
        Shape.__init__(self, shape)
        LivingThings.__init__(self,age ,name)
```

so super() dosent work in multiple inheritance??

Comment: It would if you implemented it correctly - neither superclass uses `super`, so only the first one gets called, and they have different signatures.

Comment: As well as adding appropriate `super()` calls to those `__init__` methods you need to change them so they all have the same call signature. The simple way to do that is to use a dict of keyword args, as shown in the `ColoredShape` example in the Raymond Hettinger article linked by Daniel Roseman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super` works fine in multiple inheritance; that is in fact precisely what it is for. But for some reason you are calling it twice, with different arguments; that is not how it works.

Call it once. That calls the next method in the method resolution order. It is then *that method's* responibility to call super, to call the next method.

Please read Raymond Hettinger's classic article [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: So what is the super - constructor relationship between the two parent types?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question at all. What relationship?

Comment: Raymond Hettinger also gave this as an entertaining talk at Pycon 2015: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: Method resolution order requires..  ordering.

Comment: @user2864740 yes, which you can see in the `__mro__` attribute